# Page redirection not working in codeigniter on live server, but works in local server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

this is the path to my project on server public_html/lushhire value set in session but page not redirect to to dashboard

```
   if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect(base_url('Dashboard'));
        exit;
    }
  Site link
  http://lushhire.home-arc.com/
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

RewriteCond $1 
^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|css|js|images)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you sure you can use .htaccess files on that server?

Comment: i dont no but my htaccess file is hidden

Comment: You need to have "AllowOverride All" on the apache.conf file or .htaccess files are worthless. Also all files beginning with . Are hidden on Linux